# I'm having trouble with an array in which I only need its position not value

Tags: java, arrays, loops

(java) I'm having trouble with my Mancala program in which I need to transfer my array Board[0]'s position to my array in the for loop Board[pilePlayer1+i].  All I need if for the Board[pilePlayer1+i] to be in Board[0]'s position not changing anything, and continue on with the for loop.  I'm at a loss on how to do this and any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

````
import TurtleGraphics.KeyboardReader;

public class Mancala 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
        int clicked, index = 0, pit = 0;
        boolean player1, player2;
        //arrays
        int[] Board = new int[] { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0 };
        char[] CharArrayP1 = new char[6];
        CharArrayP1[0] = 'A';
        CharArrayP1[1] = 'B';
        CharArrayP1[2] = 'C';
        CharArrayP1[3] = 'D';
        CharArrayP1[4] = 'E';
        CharArrayP1[5] = 'F';
        char[] CharArrayP2 = new char[6];
        CharArrayP2[0] = 'a';
        CharArrayP2[1] = 'b';
        CharArrayP2[2] = 'c';
        CharArrayP2[3] = 'd';
        CharArrayP2[4] = 'e';
        CharArrayP2[5] = 'f';



//method transfers
        playgame(Board, CharArrayP1, CharArrayP2);
        BoardPrintout(Board, CharArrayP1, CharArrayP2);
    }
    public static void playgame(int Board[], char[] CharArrayP1, char[] CharArrayP2)
    {
        KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
        int pilePlayer1 = 0, pilePlayer2 = 0, pC=0;
        char Char1, Char2;
        boolean p1, p2;

        do {
            pC++;
//player turn printout
            if((pC==1)||(pC==3)||(pC==5)||(pC==7)||(pC==9)||(pC==11)||(pC==13))
            {
                p1 = true; 
                System.out.println("Player 1's Turn");
            }
            else
                p1 = false;
            if((pC==2)||(pC==4)||(pC==6)||(pC==8)||(pC==10)||(pC==12)||(pC==14))
            {
                p2 = true;  
                System.out.println("Player 2's Turn");
            }
            else
                p2 = false; 
            if(p1= true)
            {

                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("Player one chose a pile (A-F Capital)");
                Char1=reader.readChar();
                //converting char to int
                if(Char1=='A')
                    pilePlayer1=0;
                if(Char1=='B')
                    pilePlayer1=1;
                if(Char1=='C')
                    pilePlayer1=2;
                if(Char1=='D')
                    pilePlayer1=3;
                if(Char1=='E')
                    pilePlayer1=4;
                if(Char1=='F')
                    pilePlayer1=5;
                while(Character.isLetter(Char1) == false) 
                {
                    //error checker player 1
                    System.err.println("Error: value wrong please rechoose your pile");
                    System.out.println("Player 1 rechose a pile (A-F Capital)");
                    Char1=reader.readChar();
                    if(Char1=='A')
                        pilePlayer1=0;
                    if(Char1=='B')
                        pilePlayer1=1;
                    if(Char1=='C')
                        pilePlayer1=2;
                    if(Char1=='D')
                        pilePlayer1=3;
                    if(Char1=='E')
                        pilePlayer1=4;
                    if(Char1=='F')
                        pilePlayer1=5;

                };
                //pile adder player 1
                for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    Board[pilePlayer1]--;
                    Board[pilePlayer1+i]++;
                    if(Board[pilePlayer1+i]==Board[13])
                    {
                        Board[13]--;
                        Board[pilePlayer1+i]=Board[0];

                    }
                }
                //board printer
                BoardPrintout(Board, CharArrayP1, CharArrayP2);
            }


            if(p2= true)
            {
                System.out.println("Player two chose a pile (a-f lowercase)");
                Char2=reader.readChar();
                //converting char to int
                if(Char2=='a')
                    pilePlayer2=7;
                if(Char2=='b')
                    pilePlayer2=8;
                if(Char2=='c')
                    pilePlayer2=9;
                if(Char2=='d')
                    pilePlayer2=10;
                if(Char2=='e')
                    pilePlayer2=11;
                if(Char2=='f')
                    pilePlayer2=12;
                while(Character.isLetter(Char2) == false)
                {
                    //error checker player 2 
                    System.err.println("Error: value wrong please rechoose your pile");
                    System.out.println("Player 2 rechose a pile (A-F Capital)");
                    Char2=reader.readChar();
                    if(Char2=='a')
                        pilePlayer2=7;
                    if(Char2=='b')
                        pilePlayer2=8;
                    if(Char2=='c')
                        pilePlayer2=9;
                    if(Char2=='d')
                        pilePlayer2=10;
                    if(Char2=='e')
                        pilePlayer2=11;
                    if(Char2=='f')
                        pilePlayer2=12;

                }while(Character.isLetter(Char2) == false);
                //pile adder player 2 (where the error is)
                for(int i=-1; i<4; i++)
                {
                    Board[pilePlayer2]--;
                    Board[pilePlayer2+i]++;
                    if(Board[pilePlayer2+i]==Board[13])
                    {
                        Board[13]--;
                        //how do i get it so it only changes position not value

                    }
                }
                BoardPrintout(Board, CharArrayP1, CharArrayP2);
            }
        }while(gameover(Board)!=false);

    }

    public static void BoardPrintout(int Board[], char[] CharArrayP1, char[] CharArrayP2) 
    {
        //BOARD
        System.out.print("\t"+CharArrayP2[5]+"\t"+CharArrayP2[4]+"\t"+CharArrayP2[3]+"\t"+CharArrayP2[2]+"\t"+CharArrayP2[1]+"\t"+CharArrayP2[0]);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("\t"+Board[12]+"\t"+Board[11]+"\t"+Board[10]+"\t"+Board[9]+"\t"+Board[8]+"\t"+Board[7]);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(Board[13]+"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"+Board[6]);
        System.out.print("\t"+CharArrayP1[0]+"\t"+CharArrayP1[1]+"\t"+CharArrayP1[2]+"\t"+CharArrayP1[3]+"\t"+CharArrayP1[4]+"\t"+CharArrayP1[5]);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("\t"+Board[0]+"\t"+Board[1]+"\t"+Board[2]+"\t"+Board[3]+"\t"+Board[4]+"\t"+Board[5]);
        System.out.println("");
    }
    // checks if the game is over
    public static boolean gameover(int[] Board){
        if (Board[0]==0||Board[1]==0||Board[2]==0||
                Board[3]==0||Board[4]==0||Board[5]==0){
            return true;
        }
        else if(Board[7]==0||Board[8]==0||Board[9]==0
                ||Board[10]==0||Board[11]==0||Board[12]==0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} ```



**Prompt**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOws6.png
````

Comment: I can't understand what problem you're having. At least, I can't understand your explanation.

Comment: Sorry I just wanted the for loop to go from Board[13] aka Board[pilePlayer2+i] to Board[0] without anything changing value wise.

Comment: for(int i=-1; i<4; i++)
                {
                    Board[pilePlayer2]--;
                    Board[pilePlayer2+i]++;
                    if(Board[pilePlayer2+i]==Board[13])
                    {
                        Board[13]--;
                        //how do i get it so it only changes position not value

                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but it looks like you want to repoint your index to the beginning of the list after your reach position 13. This can be done by using modular arithmetic when calculating the index of the array you are depositing stones into, i.e. calling `Board[(pilePlayer2+i)%13]`. You do not even need the `if` statement, as whenever your calculated index reaches 13, it will be reset to 0 by the `%13` (mod 13) part of the equation.